# how to validate a dropdown list for checking textbox value before selecting dropdown in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I've 1 textbox, its for getting DateTime value,First the user has to fill the DateTime textbox before selecting the vehicle dropdown. If that textbox is blank i ve to popup a message.. I am trying to validate but its not responding.. 
the code is,

```
function Validate_VehicleDropdown()
{
    var RequestDateTime=$get('<%=ui_txtRequestDateTime.ClientID %>')
    if(RequestDateTime.value=="")
    {
         alert("Please Enter RequestDateTime Before Selecting Vehicle");
         RequestDateTime.focus();
         return false;
    }
```

I called that function inside Dropdown control as

```
onblur="javascript:return Validate_VehicleDropdown();
```

What mistake i ve done here?? give some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you do not need to use `javascript:` in the blur part. That is primarily for hyperlinks.
Secondly, perhaps you could check your browsers JavaScript logs for errors.

In Internet Explorer 9 press <kbd>F12</kbd>

In Firefox download firebug.

In Chrome press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **onchange** event instead of onblur